# Does rails cache anything if an exception is raised?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm wondering if rails caches anything in the following case:

```
  Rails.cache.fetch("some_key", expires_in: 1.day) do
    service.call # raises exception
    []
  end
```

I'm concerned because if the request inside the `Rails.cache.fetch` block fails, I want to retry on the next request. Not make the user wait 24HRS to retry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** Rails doesn't cache anything if an exception is raised.

[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) says that the **return value** of the block will be written to the cache.

When a block raises an exception, it **doesn't return anything**, therefore nothing is cached.

Comment: I don't see any such line written in the docs. Is this still valid?

Comment: I believe it's still valid. The docs were rewritten, but the concept is still explained there. I deleted the outdated quote from my answer to avoid confusion.